# Use canvas for the GestureOverlayView

Tags: android, bitmap, gesture

I have a GestureOverlayView on which the user can draw gesture stokes, I want to save these strokes in a PNG file.
I have tried the  `public void draw (Canvas canvas)` ,and I get a PNG file as an output of my following code, but I was not able get any strokes in that, can any one help me with this....
thanks in advance.

**My code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.create_gesture);

    bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(12, 12, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    can=new Canvas(bitmap);
    GestureOverlayView overlay = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures_overlay);
    overlay.addOnGestureListener(new GesturesProcessor());
    overlay.draw(can);

}
```

**Code to save the strokes as PNG**

```
          bm=mGesture.toBitmap(313, 343, 8,3);
           can.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);

           File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                             + File.separator+"Strokes");

                      out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                     bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, out);
                     Toast.makeText(this, "PNG file Created "+mGesture, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Modification as specified by Dr.J**

```
 Paint paint=new Paint();
 Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(412, 412, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
 Canvas can=new Canvas(bitmap);
 Path path = new Path();
 paint.setColor(255);
```

.
.
.
.

```
 private class GesturesProcessor implements GestureOverlayView.OnGestureListener {
 public void onGestureEnded(final GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            mGesture = overlay.getGesture();

            try{

              path=overlay.getGesturePath();

              can.drawPath(path, paint);

              can.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
              File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                  + File.separator+"Strokes");

                           out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, out);
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Created gesture 12:56 section active "+mGesture, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }catch(Exception exp){exp.printStackTrace();}

              }
      }).start();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the gestures from the user directly, the Canvas given to you from Draw(Canvas canvas) is for you to draw on, it doesn't hold data for you to capture from.

You should use:

```
   public Path getGesturePath (Path path)
```

Then if you want to save it use the Canvas's drawPath [AndDev Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)

```
. It can be drawn with canvas.drawPath(path, paint), either filled or stroked (based on the paint's Style), or it can be used for clipping or to draw text on a path.
```

Comment: thanks for the responding...i have made the changes you have mentioned in the code, but still i get empty png files, i have the modified codes in my question space

Comment: you need to grab the Path **FROM** the GestureOverlayView from the Listener like the [OnGesturePerformedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener.html) from where you will proceed to use the overlay and call (the listener's) overlay.getGesturePath(Path),  You can then use the Path to draw onto a canvas to save the gesture.

Comment: i have made the changes ..you mean like that (above modification)

Comment: that should work, but the UI may die if it takes too long for you to save the file.  You will need to make a AsyncTask and have it handle saving the file at request when ran with a Path object.

A ["short" reference stuff](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) about the UI thread and AsyncTasks